# Get index of unordered list and scroll position (up and down) on click

Tags: jquery

I have a schedule of events, the ul has a fixed height and overflow hidden, the li's also have a fixed height. Only four are visible at a time. I need to figure out how to scroll through the list, both up and down on click of the appropriate button.

I'm sure there are plug ins out there that can do this, but for a better understanding of jQuery/JS I want to do this on my own - but need some help. HTML/CSS is here http://jsfiddle.net/DirtyBirdDesign/BJdJ7/

I have broken this down into the following needs:

1. Loop through and index the number of list items
2. Get the current position
3. on each click of the 'down' button, move the position -41px
4. on each click of the 'up' button, move the position +41px
5. animate the transition
6. Loop continuously - go from last to first when last is visible

Am I missing anything on the above? How do I go about this?
thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: I gave you a pretty working answer, I can make it **exactly meet** your needs! But don't you want to make a little effort?

Comment: I do, but I'm not making the complete connection. I was thinking that I need to get an index of the child li's and loop through them on each click. I can move positioning, but ran into the same issue your solution has - simply adding more whitespace before and after the first and last item when clicking the up/down button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change position:relative CSS to your li

```
#PartnerSchedule ul#PartnerEvents li {
  position:relative;
  width:457px;
  height:41px;
  margin:0 0 2px 0;
  padding:0 10px;
  font:.9em/1.75em "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Genevea, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

This script is a solution for you, you may add controls to stop scrolling when your limit is reached.

```
​$('#up').click(function(){
    $('#PartnerEvents li').animate({top:'-=43'});
});
$('#down').click(function(){
    $('#PartnerEvents li').animate({top:'+=43'});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BJdJ7/1/)
​

Comment: note that it should be **43** pixels because your li have a 2pixels margin-bottom

Comment: Very good! I have edited the needs of this, based on your example. I need it to loop continuously, that is when the last one is visible, and next is clicked cycle back to the first one. Currently it just keeps adding space if you click previous when first is visible and vice versa when last is visible

Comment: here is what you should do: when you click **up**, check if the **last** li is within the visible area, check [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) if so, append the first li after it<br> now just use your brain to guess how to do with the **down** button..

Comment: Need a little push here, I think I get the concept - checking if it's offset is within specific margin, if not move it up. Would you define the visible are first in a var, then check against it? I really appreciate the help and like learning this way... hope it's not a pain in  your ass.

Comment: here is a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/BJdJ7/8/ I really hope you try to understand it and not to just use my code..

Comment: To me this is best because it is the simplest, lightest etc. If I could impose on you one last time - I would like to make sure I understand it. You're declaring the first var > hiding the first on "up" click and animating with 'blind' animation .... what I don't get is the last part, you're then showing the new first li? how does the append/prepend not apply to the actual first/last in the list?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10854/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-skafandri)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->  

var itemsToShow = 4;

$('#PartnerEvents>li').each(function(i,k) {
    var ele = $(this);
    $(ele).attr('id', 'PartnerEvents' + i);
    if (i >= itemsToShow) //i is zero indexed
    {
        $(ele).hide();
    }
});


$('#up').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#PartnerEvents0:hidden').length > 0)
    {
        // This means we can go up
        var boundaryTop = $('#PartnerEvents li:visible:first').attr('id');
        var boundaryBottom = $('#PartnerEvents li:visible:last').attr('id');

        if ($('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryTop).prev().length > 0)
        {
            $('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryTop).prev().show();
            $('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryBottom).hide();
        }
    }
});

$('#down').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#PartnerEvents li:last:hidden').length > 0)
    {
        // This means we can go down
        var boundaryTop = $('#PartnerEvents li:visible:first').attr('id');
        var boundaryBottom = $('#PartnerEvents li:visible:last').attr('id');

        if ($('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryBottom).next().length > 0)
        {
            $('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryBottom).next().show();
            $('#PartnerEvents li#'+ boundaryTop).hide();
        }
}
});
```

Comment: I have just added it in my main post, not sure why id didn't show on jsfiddle

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. After going down through the list, clicking up is removing li's - http://jsfiddle.net/DirtyBirdDesign/BJdJ7/6/

Comment: Note in the HTML section the a tags for the first 2 li's are not closed properly. This is causing the error. http://jsfiddle.net/BJdJ7/7/

Comment: Ahh, sloppy pasting on my part from real file to jsfiddle.. thx! Well it works, unfortunately I don't really grasp it that well. I really appreciate it - I'll try and figure it out. Where/how would one go about adding an animation to it, just a simple slide up/down

Comment: No problem.
Simply where you see .hide() replace that with .slideUp() and where you see .show() replace that with .slideDown()

Comment: All good, thx. One question, how would you make it loop so if you're at the last one and you hit down it displays the first?

Comment: That's not as simple, as this is simply traversing through the li elements. The only way to what you want is to get the html of the first li and append it to the ul list. However I would suggest not to do this.